# Rails3 URI() if condition not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :store_ref_url

  def store_ref_url
    rf = request.referer
    if ((URI(rf.to_s).host != "dev-beta.foo.com") && (URI(rf.to_s).host != "beta.foo.com") && URI(rf.to_s).port != "3000")
      session['referer'] = request.referer
    end
  end
end
```

If the domain is "dev-beta.foo.com" or "beta.foo.com" or the port is 3000 in my local machine, I dont like to save the request.referer in my session['referer']. But it still keeps on saving it. I already tried several conditions. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked your `session` before trying this out?  When are you clearing your session?  Is it possible that you already had your session set earlier and in your consecutive tries you think that your session is getting set?  The if condition looks fine.

Comment: Yes I check it using <%=debug session['referer']-%> in my view. I set it to nil after the redirect in my controller. I really think the if statement is just fine, but I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: See my comment below.  The last condition is comparing a Fixnum to a string "3000", so clearly the logic is not performing how you intended.  Just open up a console and test everything out one by one, that will take a lot less time.

Comment: @tyler you are correct about the data type of the port number. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

It looks like you're trying to determine when you're running in staging or development vs production, in which case you can simply use:

```
Rails.env.production?
```

To get that information.  You can also set up a staging environment to deploy on your dev-beta.foo.com site, where you could just use `Rails.env.staging?` the same way.

To debug the specific question you asked, just find out what the request.referer variable is on a request that is failing your test, then open up a console and test your logic conditions one at a time and then together to see what conditions are failing.

Finally, my personal preference would be to see the logic conditions placed on the before filter itself, but that may not be a universal sentiment.

**EDIT**
I might also add that your last condition `!= "3000"` is probably not doing anything; I don't think the `port` method returns a string...

Comment: I have a devise authentication server running and this is where I'll use the code in order to redirect back the users after they successfully login. Yes I'm aware about the Rails.env.production? but the one I'm trying to detect runs in a separate Rails App.

Comment: Not sure why you'd want that setup, but you could always just set it to be an "authentication" environment.  Then you could do Rails.env.authentication? to get what you need.  What is the use case for having a separate app run devise authentication???

Comment: Because the company where I work owns several domains, each with a separate Rails app. The devise server is for single sign on. Thanks for the advice. I'll try to make it work.